# How to arrange Xticks in ggplot for categorical variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having trouble visualizing the "sex" variable (Female=0, Male=1) from the "heart_data" dataframe. Here's my code:

> ggplot(heart_data, aes(x = sex)) + geom_bar()

And this is what I obtain:

[image]

What should I do in order to display just 0 and 1 or, preferably, Female and Male on the Xaxis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display 0/1 on x-axis convert `sex` to factor.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

hear_data %>%
  mutate(sex = factor(sex)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = sex)) + geom_bar()
```

To display Female/Male recode 0/1 value.

```
hear_data %>%
  mutate(sex = recode(sex, `1` = 'Male', `0` = 'Female')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = sex)) + geom_bar()
```